# С++ циклы многократное увеличение числа на 1

Tags: c++, циклы, арифметика

Есть код 1888000721011000001 нужна составить цикл в С++ чтобы он увеличивался на единицу
в итоге должен получиться столбец из кодов
который начинается
1888000721011000001
1888000721011000002
1888000721011000003
и заканчивается
1888000721011000297
1888000721011000298
1888000721011000299
1888000721011000300
строк может быть 200, 300 может 1000 без разницы.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace  std;

int main()

{
    int x;
    int y = 188800072101100000;
    int sum;
    for (x = 1; x < 301; x++) {

        
        cout <<  endl<< 188800072101100000 << x;

    }
}
```

Comment: В тип `int` такое длинное число не влезает. Можете ознакомиться с максимальными и минимальными значениями типов в `/usr/include/limits.h`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И в чем проблема?

```
cout <<  "1888000721011000" << setw(3) << setfill('0') << x;
```

[решит вашу проблему](https://ideone.com/Jk33j9) :)

Есть и [другой вариант](https://ideone.com/BXHPli)

```
long long y = 1888000721011000000;
for (x = 1; x < 301; x++) cout << y+x << endl;
```